# C# Timer with Multiple Events

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to implement a C# timer in my code. A simplified version of my code is below.

1. CommandReceived is fired when my application receives commands from an external system to operate different devices. In this example emitting lights.
2. I use a timer to handle the duration that lights must be switched on then call a method to switch off the lights once the timer is elapsed.
3. CommandReceived will be fired multiple times while the timer is ticking. timer must be able to handle different duration for different devices correctly, without resting the existing ticks.
4. I have achieved the expected behavior by using multiple timers at the moment. (one timer for each device). I am trying to achieve the same using a single timer.
5. Here's my code using a single timer and multiple events, however this code doesn't handle multiple duration at the moment.

Ex : If I trigger CommandReceived for device 1 flash led for 5 secs, device 2 steady led for 10 secs, OnDevice1ElapsedEvent and OnDevice2ElapsedEvent both fire after 10 secs.

Appreciate If someone can advise a way to achieve this. It would be great if this can be achieved by using just one ElapsedEvent too.

```
class CommandExecute
{

    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public void CommandReceived(string device, string action, int duration)
    {
        // Ex : action : flash light 5 secs, steady light 3 secs
        // Ex : device : device 1, device 2

        switch (action)
        {
            case "flash" :
                FlashLight(device);
                ConfigureTimer(device, duration);
                break;
            case "steady" :
                SteadyLight(device);
                ConfigureTimer(device, duration);
                break;
            default:break;
        }

    }

    private void ConfigureTimer(string device, int duration)
    {
        if (_timer == null)
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Interval = duration;
        switch (device)
        {
            case "device 1":
                _timer.Elapsed += OnDevice1ElapsedEvent;
                break;
            case "device 2":
                _timer.Elapsed += OnDevice2ElapsedEvent;
                break;
        }

        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnDevice1ElapsedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        LightOff("device1");
        _timer.Elapsed -= OnDevice1ElapsedEvent;
    }

    private void OnDevice2ElapsedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        LightOff("device2");
        _timer.Elapsed -= OnDevice2ElapsedEvent;
    }

    private void FlashLight(string device)
    {
        //Flashing Light
    }

    private void SteadyLight(string device)
    {
        //Steady Light
    }

    private void LightOff(string device)
    {
        //Light Off
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one unknown behaviour in your statement, if you execute the command multiple times e.g. executing 2 commands in a row after 1 second on device 1 flash led, are you expecting it to extend 1 second duration or do nothing or queue another command. ideally you should execute each device in different thread/timer or you can create one thread dedicated to turn off light for all devices.

Comment: it should queue another command.
I don't want to turn off light all devices at once. each device should turn of after respective time has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do away with the timers and make FlashLight async, like this:

```
public async Task FlashLight(Device device, int seconds)
{
    device.TurnLightOn();
    await Task.Delay(seconds * 1000);
    device.TurnLightOff();
}
```

Then just call it asynchronously when you want to start the light flashing:

```
await FlashLight(device, 3);
```

Or if you don't want to make your event handler async (even though there is no down side) you could use:

```
Task.Run( () => FlashLight(device, 3) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConcurrentQueue` or `BlockingCollection` to just queue up your received commands. When your app starts up, you can run an infinite loop on a threadpool thread that just reads from this collection and performs the action:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<Command> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Command>();

//wherever your start point it
void Main()
{
    Task.Run(()=> ProcessAsync());
}

async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    while(true)
    {
       if(_queue.TryDequeue(out var command))
       {

           switch(command.Action)
           {
              case "flash" : FlashLight(command.Device); break;
              case "steady" : SteadyLight(command.Device); break;
           }
           // wait for duration to end, then we switch off the device
           await Task.Delay(command.Duration * 1000);
           LightOff(command.Device);
       }
    }
}

public void CommandReceived(string device, string action, int duration)
{
    _queue.Enqueue(new Command { Device = device, Action = action, Duration = duration});
}


public class Command
{
    public string Device {get;set;}
    public string Action {get;set;}
    public int Duration {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: If you are going to run a thread for ever, I don't recommend using a thread pool thread.

Comment: Im not following. Either we use a background thread from threadpool or main thread, not sure where else we would be running this work. Grabbing a single thread is trivial.

Comment: `var threadToRun = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadProc (DoYourBackgroundWork()); threadToRun.Start();` will get your work running on a new, non-thread-pool thread.  I'm not saying that dedicating a thread to this is necessarily a good idea, just that, if you do, you shouldn't use a thread pool thread.

Comment: Oh right. I hear what you're saying but I will still opt for Task based implementation. It is lighter to start, threadpool manages the resources better and if in future that method changes to have some sort of *actual* `async` IO to perform, i can still use `async/await` pattern.